# Is it possible to autostart a VMware virtual machine in background as a Linux service in Ubuntu, and shut it down elegantly when Ubuntu shuts down?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, shutdown

The host is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I would like my virtual machine to start with Ubuntu in the background. I also hope the virtual machine can be shut down elegantly upon Windows shuts down.

Is there any existing project or init script that does this for me?

Comment: There was an answer that actually solved this problem but it was deleted... The script it mentioned can be found here: https://gist.github.com/tommybutler/7517679. If you use VMware Player instead of VMware Workstation, replace the three occurrences of `vmrun` with `vmrun -T player` in that script.

Comment: It Was deleted for quality reasons.